# How to add items to a Listview without using a database?

Tags: android, listview

I've already exhausted my efforts on this one but can't seem to find answers. So our instructor told us not to use Database. So the app is like filling up a form, asking for your picture, lastname, firstname and your course and then will display the items on your listview which is another activity.

How can I do this without using a database? Thanks! Please check out the my code below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    StudentAdapter studentAdapter;
    ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, studentArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
    }


    //back button
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_add){
            Intent add = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddStudentActivity.class);
            startActivity(add);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //show add menu

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

StudentAdapter.java

```
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    //contructor


    public StudentAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.studentArrayList = studentArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return studentArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return studentArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.lname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLName);
            holder.fname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFName);
            holder.course = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCourse);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        //
        holder.image.setImageResource(studentArrayList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.lname.setText(studentArrayList.get(position).getLname());
        holder.fname.setText(studentArrayList.get(position).getFname());
        holder.course.setText(studentArrayList.get(position).getCourse());

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView lname, fname, course;
    }
```

AddStudentActivity.java

```
    ImageView studentImage;
    EditText studLname, studFname;
    Button btnSave, btnCancel;
    Spinner cboCourse;
    String selectedCourse;
    Uri imageUri;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    StudentAdapter studentAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_student);

        //
        studentImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        studLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        studFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        cboCourse = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

        cboCourse.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        studentImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Unsaved Changes");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("LEAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.imageView2:
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
                break;
            case R.id.btnsave:
                if(studLname.equals("") || studFname.equals("") || cboCourse.getSelectedItem().equals(0)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    //add a statement to add an item here
                studentArrayList.add(studentImage.getResources().toString(), studLname.getText().toString(), studFname.getText().toString(), cboCourse.getSelectedItem());

//                    studentArrayList.add(studentImage.getBaseline(), studLname.getText().toString(), studFname.getText().toString(), cboCourse.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent home = new Intent(AddStudentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                    studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btncancel:
                studLname.setText("");
                studFname.setText("");
                break;
        }
    }

    //handles opening the camera

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            studentImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //for the spinner
        int sid = parent.getId();

        switch (sid){
            case R.id.spinner:
                selectedCourse = this.cboCourse.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Student.java

```
package com.example.studentinfoapplication;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Student implements Serializable {

    private int image;
    private String lname, fname, course;

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Storage options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Comment: I just don't know how to use `arraylist.add()`

Comment: NO database means no persistent storage . SO you will just use runtime memory here .. Just create a class `Student` each time user submits details create a Object of `Student` set Values and add it to list then notify the adapter ..

Comment: I already created that but I don't know how to call them in my `arraylist.add()` because it is giving me an error

Comment: What error ? I do not see `studentArrayList .add` anywhere in your code ..

Comment: cannot resolve method 'add'. I will update my code.

Comment: Already updated my code

Comment: Do you have a class with getters and setters?

Comment: Can you post your Student class?

Comment: Is it part of the design requirements that adding students and viewing the Listview be two separate activities?

Comment: @SammyT yes it is part of the requirements

Comment: @Vince yes I have. Please check my updated post

Comment: I don't know if this would be the best method. But, if you don't mind creating a version of your Student class that implements `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable`, you can store `Parcelable` arrays in your `Intents` when you're navigating between Activities.

Comment: Your studentArrayList values type is your 'Student' class and                 studentArrayList.add(studentImage.getResources().toString(), studLname.getText().toString(), studFname.getText().toString(), cboCourse.getSelectedItem()); wont work because you're adding Strings.

Comment: Change it to ArrayList<String> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); or use the getters/setters in your Student class.

Comment: I also see that set/get image in your Student class asks for an int type? Do you want to show the image in the next activity or only the path of the image?

Comment: @Vince I want to show the uploaded image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Student class**

I added a global Arraylist to your Student Class.

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

public static ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

   private Uri image;
   private String lname, fname, course;

   public Student(){      //Add your constructor.

   }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

StudentAdapter studentAdapter;
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    Log.d("test", "students" + Student.studentArrayList);

    if (Student.studentArrayList != null) {
        studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, Student.studentArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
    }
}
```

**AddStudentActivity**

```
 ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Remove this line at the top because we are referring to the global arraylist in Student class.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.imageView2:
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
                break;
            case R.id.btnsave:
                if(!studLname.equals("") || !studFname.equals("") || !cboCourse.getSelectedItem().equals(0)){

                    String lname = studLname.getText().toString();
                    String fname = studFname.getText().toString();
                    String course = cboCourse.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    student.setLname(lname);
                    student.setFname(fname);
                    student.setCourse(course);

                    Student.studentArrayList.add(student); //Global arraylist

                    Log.d("test", "students:" + Student.studentArrayList);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent home = new Intent(AddStudentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                break;
            case R.id.btncancel:
                studLname.setText("");
                studFname.setText("");
                cboCourse.setSelection(0);
                break;
        }
    }

   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        if (data != null) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
        }
        student.setImage(imageUri);
        studentImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

**StudentAdapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.lname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLName);
        holder.fname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textFName);
        holder.course = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textCourse);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //
    holder.lname.setText(studentArrayList.get(position).getLname());
    holder.fname.setText(studentArrayList.get(position).getFname());
    holder.image.setImageURI(studentArrayList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.course.setText(studentArrayList.get(position).getCourse());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your efforts. Because I have put their an int for an image which is not intended because I want to show the image URI.

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo change the type to Uri uri and then pass the Uri from onActivityResult to your Student class setter student.setImage(imageUri);

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo i edited my answer and now it should work and in your second activity just get your valued with the getters from the student class.

Comment: I am having an error with this one `student = new Student(this);` It says Student() in Student cannot be applied

Comment: When I add this `student.setImage(imageUri);` on my `OnActivityResult`, the application will stop. Any idea why?

Comment: Your missing your constructor in Student class.

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo i edited my answer, check Student class.

Comment: @BeverlyCastillo does it crash your app or just close it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196019/discussion-between-beverly-castillo-and-vince).

Answer (score 0):

There can be couple of approaches you can try 
a) Create singleton class and maintain a list of students that you add and then use the same singleton object in mainactivity to populate list.

b) create serializable/parcellable model having list of studuent ,every time you add the student and send this list to main activity and vice versa to use same model b/w two activities. This is just workaround apprach. I will prefer first one.